# good tool to slice PSD to CSS+HTML output

Tags: html, css, slice, psd

Is there any tool to slice PSD design that generates CSS+HTML (not excellent, but as a starting point). I hear that photoshop has some wysiwyg-editor that generates CSS+HTML output on sliced PSD, but didn't find anything. Or is there any good tutorial that could help me as developer with this tricky css situations (as an gradient div background and shadows adding without unsupported css3). Sorry for so stupid question, but i'm really stuck about this "design" as developer.

Answer (score 2):

I use psd2cssonline.com - you can create basic html/css for free and if you want more complex css you can subscribe to the pro service. Both versions are fantastic - it really helped me learn css. Basically in photoshop you name your psd layers according to what sort of css element you want each layer to be (background, text field, footer, rollover, image etc) and then upload it to the site, preview and download the output.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there are many tutorials but for a starting point have a look at these:

**http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/freebies/psd-htmlcss-conversion-tutorials/**

**http://www.ehow.com/how_8391171_export-psd-css.html**

**http://www.warriorforum.com/website-design/199348-best-psd-html-tool.html**

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

My company makes a Photoshop plugin called SiteGrinder which converts Photoshop designs into finished web sites or WordPress themes.  http://www.medialab.com

There are also many slicing services you can send a .psd to.